Spring (Not Spring Boot) Alternative Config File Location
I am trying to config Spring 4.3 (Not Spring Boot) alternative config file location in Windows using Tomcat's catalina.bat file:
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Dspring.config.location=D:\Software\apache-tomcat-8.5.47-1\conf\Catalina\localhost\env\

This is a directory.
But upon startup, I am getting

nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [env/application-default.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

But the file is in the specified directory. I cannot start the application.
I want to know how to do it for Spring application (Not Spring Boot).

spring.config.location is a Spring Boot property, it will not do anything for a regular Spring application.

Then how do I do it for regular Spring application?
